# Is there a way to use the Artifacts feed for my updates using Squirrel?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, squirrel.windows

I have a C# Console application(.Net Framework) that I want to update using [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows). I have my program on Azure DevOps, which has an integrated Nuget feed in the Artifacts section.

Squirrel uses nuget packages to update the application. Is there a way that I can upload the packages that Squirrel generates as Artifacts in order for my program to use them?

It's ok if the program needs to download those packages in the local machine and then let Squirrel do its work with the file in the computer. In my head, it seems to be the only workaround. Any suggestion?

This is my first question so if it's hard to understand please tell me and I will try to write it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can upload the packages that Squirrel generates
>   as Artifacts in order for my program to use them?

If the `packages that Squirrel generates` indicates the nuget packages ending with `.nupkg`, of course you can upload them to Azure Devops feed. See [Publish a feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops#publish-a-package). But the Azure Devops nuget feed can only host nuget packages, if you want to host other files like `xx.exe` or `xx.msi`, you should use the [Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops).

But if you want to use the package hosted in Azure Devops Artifact feed for auto-updating, I think it's not supported, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops): To consume packages from Private Azure Devops feed, you have to complete authentication. And I think this will impact normal [Squirrel updating process](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/5-updating.md). So in my opinion, you can't use Artifact for your Squirrel updating.

Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :)